# Error criteria.list using key composite

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Entity

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "entidade")
public class Entidade {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6831078183847196839L;
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id_titulo", column = @Column(name = "titulo_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id_empresa", column = @Column(name = "empresa_id", nullable = false)) })
    private PK pk;
//getter//setter
}
```

//PK

```
@Embeddable
public class PK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5441836698300495848L;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id_titulo")
    private Long titulo_id;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id_empresa")
    private Long empresa_id;

        //getter // setter
}
```

Query is OK : if instance pk setter

```
  Criteria criteria = novoCriteria();
    criteria.createAlias("id", "id");
    TituloPK pk = new TituloPK();
    pk.setEmpresa(2L);
    pk.setTitulo(6364L);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", pk));
    criteria.list();
```

Query error

```
   Criteria criteria = novoCriteria();
    criteria.createAlias("id", "id");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.id_empresa", 2L));
    criteria.list();
```

Error in console  :  ***could not resolve property: id_empresa of:   Entidade***

need only search by company, and if I use the constraint returns the above error.

Comment: It seems like `id_empresa` is the column name. You need to replace it with the java field of the class `Entidade` -> `id.javaField` (maybe `id.pk`, but I dunno what `EmbeddedId` does)

Comment: Add your `PK` class to your question so that we can check whether you are using the right syntax to add the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

In `Criteria`, as you know, you must use the name of the member of the class, not the name of the field in your database. But the `@AttributeOverride` annotation is not overriding this attribute in the `PK` class, but only in the `Entidade` class. So you must use the name of the attribute as it is declared in your `PK` class, that is `id.empresa_id`.

So your code should be:

```
Criteria criteria = novoCriteria();
    criteria.createAlias("id", "id");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.empresa_id", 2L));
    criteria.list();
```

In one of my project, I could reproduce your error and could solve it using the name of the parameter in the embeddable class. I think it should work for you as well.

Comment: I made a mistake first, because I didn't see the `@AttributeOverride`, so I decided to delete my answer. But now, I think this solution is the correct one. Tell me if you could solve your problem with this tip.